# How to summarize information over the dynamic period in sql?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with orders and the following fields:

```sql
create table orders2 (
  orderID int,
  customerID int,
  date DateTime,
  amount int) 
engine=Memory;
```

Each customer can make 0 or many orders each day. I need to create an SQL query that will show for each customer how many orders he/she made during the period of 3 days starting from the day when the customer has made his/her first order.

So, for each customer, the query should detect the date of the first order, then compute the date that is 3 days in the future from the first date, then filter rows to take only orders with dates in the given range, and then perform counting of orders (orderID) in that time period. At the moment, I was able to just detect the date of the first order for each customer.

```
 SELECT 
    O.customerID, 
    O.date AS first_day, 
    COUNT(O.orderID) AS first_day_orders_num, 
    SUM(O.amount) AS first_day_amount
 FROM orders2 AS O
 INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        customerID, 
        MIN(date) AS first_date
    FROM orders2
    GROUP BY customerID
) AS I ON (O.customerID = I.customerID) AND (O.date = I.first_date)
GROUP BY 
    O.customerID, 
    O.date
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: sorry, could you show the result of your efforts to resolve the issue, not only ask the question

Comment: @vladimir I was able to count the number of orders and the sum of their amount for each customer in the day of his/her first order:

Comment: Please see my updated question. But I don't understand how to get similar results for the period of time starting from the `first_day` for each customer and ending 3 days after the `first_day`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what result do you need. Probably it can be solved using arrays.

Here is solution using vanilla sql

```
select customerID, min(first_date), sum(num_orders_per_day)
from ( 
   select customerID, date, min(date) first_date, count() num_orders_per_day
   from orders2
   group by customerID, date
   having date <= first_date + interval 3 days
   )
group by customerID
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I have replaced this part:
`date <= first_date + interval 3 days` by this:
`date <= addDays(first_date, 3)` and it works exactly as I expected.

Comment: yeah,  x + interval 3 day / x + toIntervalDay(3) / addDays(x , 3) /  are synonyms, but I prefer   `interval 3 day` because it's more readable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to get the first order date:

```
select o.CustomerID, count(*) as num_orders_3_days
from (select o.*, min(date) over (partition by CustomerID) as min_date
      from orders o
     ) o
where date < min_date + interval '3 day'
group by CustomerID;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that Clickhouse doesn't support window functions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT customerID, orders_count
FROM  (
  SELECT customerID, 
    arraySort(x -> x.1, groupArray((date, orderID))) sorted_date_per_order_pairs,
    sorted_date_per_order_pairs[1].1 + INTERVAL 3 day AS end_date,
    arrayFilter(x -> x.1 < end_date, sorted_date_per_order_pairs) orders_in_period,
    length(orders_in_period) orders_count
  FROM orders2
  GROUP BY customerID);
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works well, but the approach with vanilla SQL is more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: @kohek welcome ;) Just check - are you sure that 'vanilla sql' by Denis works correctly? The result of 'vanilla script' should not be same as result of 'array script'.

Comment: I checked on my table and it seems that the results were as I expected...